# Simplifying ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My json data given below,

```
person = ["name": "Alex", "Cities": [{"1": "Boulder"}, {"2": "Longmont"}, {"5": "Denver"}]]
```

And view I used to iterate all cities as below,

```
<div id="information">
   <div ng-repeat="city in person.Cities" >
       <div ng-repeat="(id, name) in city" >
        {{name}}
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This approach is working but to display city name two ng-repeat controller used. I am looing simple way to list the cities.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Since you have an array whose elements contain arrays, you need two loops. Why do you want to avoid using two `ng-repeat`s?

Comment: person is an object or an array ? I see only one loop necessary here, for the cities..

Comment: @ Anders Ekdahl: All dictionary items under "Cities" has only one element. That's why I am looking to have one ng-repeat to display city name.

Comment: @Bixi : person is an object.

Comment: can you refactor your JSON object format ? It would help ...

Answer (score 1):

Your data is nested, that means one array within another array. There is not way around these two loops.

You could restructure you data before you let it render so it will only take one loop to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON can be simplified;

```
person = ["name": "Alex", "Cities": {"1": "Boulder", "2": "Longmont", "5": "Denver"}]
```

And then

```
<div id="information">
    <div ng-repeat="(id, cityName) in person.Cities" >
        {{cityName}}
    </div>  
</div>
```

If you'd like to keep the citiies nested;

```
person = ["name": "Alex", "Cities": {"1": {name: "Boulder", somethingElse: 'something'}}]
```

And iterate like

```
<div id="information">
    <div ng-repeat="(id, cityData) in person.Cities" >
        {{cityData.name}}
    </div>  
</div>
```